# Problema para estabelecer uma conexão entre Cliente.exe e Servidor.exe usando o serviço No-ip

Tags: vb.net, tcpclient

Tenho um aplicativo de acesso remoto e precisava receber conexões dos meus clientes utilizando o serviço `No-ip` (no-ip.com), tendo em vista que **ip** externo é sempre dinâmico.
Então eu já tenho feito todas as configurações corretamente (do lado Servidor.exe) tais como:

- Liberei as portas necessárias no modem
- Desativei o firewall do Windows

Até agora não obtive sucesso para estabelecer esta conexão (com ip local usando Cliente.exe e Servidor.exe na mesma rede, funciona perfeitamente).

Então, atualmente estou utilizando o seguinte código abaixo para tentar estabelecer esta conexão

usando o serviço `No-ip` (no-ip.com):

```
Public Class SocketClient
  Private C As TcpClient
    Public Function IsIPAddressValid(ByVal addrString As String) As Boolean
      Dim address As IPAddress
      Return IPAddress.TryParse(addrString, address)
    End Function

  Sub Connect(ByVal h As String, ByVal p As Integer)
    Dim ipAddr As System.Net.IPAddress
    Dim ipEndPoint As System.Net.IPEndPoint
      Try
        Try
          If C IsNot Nothing Then
            C.Close()
            C = Nothing
          End If
          Catch ex As Exception
        End Try
        Do Until IsBuzy = False
        Threading.Thread.CurrentThread.Sleep(1)
        Loop
        Try
          ipAddr = IPAddress.Parse(h)
          ipEndPoint = New System.Net.IPEndPoint(ipAddr, p)
          C = New TcpClient(ipEndPoint)
          C.Connect(ipEndPoint)
          MessageBox.Show("Ok") ' Devido ao erro, esta mensagem nunca aparece
          Dim t As New Threading.Thread(AddressOf RC, 10)
            t.Start()
            RaiseEvent Connected()
          Catch ex As Exception
        End Try
        Catch ex As Exception RaiseEvent Disconnected()
      End Try
    End Sub

Function conn() As String
  Dim inStream As StreamReader
  Dim webRequest As WebRequest
  Dim webresponse As WebResponse
  Dim ip As String = Nothing
  Dim tfk As New Thread(Sub()
  Try
    webRequest = webRequest.Create(Decrypt1("kTbXQyC7KwzyNTyQNzfQqN0rg2CMhKdwNWvBts6hS7Q=")) 'Url para o arquivo .txt remoto
    webresponse = webRequest.GetResponse()
    inStream = New StreamReader(webresponse.GetResponseStream())
    ip = inStream.ReadToEnd()
    If Not IsIPAddressValid(ip) Then
      Dim hostname As IPHostEntry = Dns.GetHostByName(ip)  ' Pega o endereço No-ip contido no arquivo .txt remoto
      Dim Noip As IPAddress() = hostname.AddressList
      ip = Noip(0).ToString() 'Endereço No-ip convertido para o ip externo correspondente
    End If
    Catch ex As Exception
  End Try
  End Sub)
  tfk.Start()
  tfk.Join()
  Return ip

End Function
```

End Class

**''''''''' Form1.vb (Cliente.exe) '''''''''''**

```
Public Class Form1

Public WithEvents C As New SocketClient

Public HOST As String = Nothing
Public port As Integer

Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load

HOST = C.conn 
Dim port = 92

End Sub

Private Sub Timer2_Tick(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Timer2.Tick
        If C.Statconnected = False Then
            C.Connect(HOST, port)
        End If
    End Sub

End Class
```

Alguém tem alguma ideia do que possa estar acontecendo e possa me ajudar com este grave problema?

Já tentei de várias formas com relação ao uso do `TcpClient.Connect()` e classe `IPEndPoint`, mas até agora nada de sucesso.

Entretanto, quaisquer outras sugestões serão bem recebidas!

Comment: Creio que essa pergunta esteja fora do escopo do SO, mas vou te dar uma dica. Tem que fazer o NAT no seu roteador (algo como VMZ). Procure como fazer NAT no seu roteador.

Comment: @MarcosRegis, fiz o procedimento indicado, mas não obtive sucesso. Com a sua experiência como programador VB.NET, poderia me dizer se estou indo no caminho certo em relação aos métodos `Conn` e `Connect` acima?

Comment: O Problema não é de programação e sim de configuração de rede. Não tenho experiência com VB.NET usando Objetos Socket mas como mencionou que o código funciona com outra configuração, só me resta crer que é problema de Rede mesmo.

Comment: @MarcosRegis, acho que você tinha razão, até achei [esta postagem](http://www.vbforums.com/showthread.php?506751-RESOLVED-VB-Net-TCPClient-Connection-Error-10049) que retrata exatamente o mesmo problema meu, eu segui o passo a passo que o autor fez lá pra resolver, mas aqui não funcionou. Inclusive, em relação ao passo 2 sugerido, fiz exatamente igual [veja](http://i.imgur.com/3OKJlz3.png), e nenhum firewall está ativo aqui. [Aqui](http://i.imgur.com/aKtI9bD.png) é a sua dica do DMZ. E o meu TcpListener está assim: `TL = New TcpListener(Ipaddress.Parse("192.168.25.116"), 100)`.

Comment: Creio que eu estou seguindo corretamente todos as dicas :-)

Comment: `Desativei o firewall do Windows` Isso não é uma configuração necessária e expõe a sua máquina a riscos.